# ¿Cómo puedo trasferir saldo entre usuarios cumpliendo ciertas condiciones en mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Necesito realizar una trasaccion entre usuarios en mysql. Es decir, necisto trasferir saldo desde un usuario A a un Usuario B. Pero nosé como incluir las condiciones y hacer Commit o rollback cuando sea necesario. Tengo el siguiente código.

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE  cuentas
SET     saldo = IF(saldo - 200 > 0, saldo-200, false) WHERE cuenta = "a";
UPDATE cuentas
SET saldo = (saldo +200) WHERE cuenta ="b";
select* from cuentas
COMMIT;
```

Necesito incorporar que los usarios no pueden tener saldo negativo y por lo tanto no se haga la transaccion.

Así como está si el usuario A, si el saldo es menor a 200 me lo deja en 0 pero el usuario B recibe los 200 aunque el A no los tenía.

Ayuda !!

Comment: Usa la función [`row_count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) para condicionar el segundo `UPDATE` y el `commit`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de procedimientos almacenados o funciones, donde puedes usar condicionales y además hacer uso también de transacciones *(commit, rollback,etc)*, te dejo enlaces con documentación en el uso de estas cosas en **MySQL**, tanto en ejemplos como en video

[Triggers, procedimientos y funciones en MySQL](https://josejuansanchez.org/bd/unidad-12-teoria/index.html)

[Curso de MySQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPvTWjwwxD8&list=PLIygiKpYTC_4KmkW7AKH87nDWtb29jHvN) (Procedimientos almacenados están desde el video #79)